# Issue with styles in Delphi XE5, linked to Mainmenu

Tags: delphi, menu, delphi-xe5, vcl-styles

I have made the transfer from Delphi 5 to Delphi XE5 some time ago and have also started making use of the styles option.
When converting  one of my older programs from *5* to *XE5*, everything  works still fine when I use the style “windows”, but the moment I change to another style, the mainmenu disappears and all objects in the form move up.  The toolbar is drawn over the main menu.  Note that the tBitBtn and tCombobox on the toolbar are not drawn in this case, but even removing these elements from the toolbar does not resolve the issue.

**Main menu issue**

[image]

After some trying I found out that this problem is linked to some of the menu items having their ‘enable’ put to false.  **Enabling** all menu items make the screen drawn correct again.

My main problem is that I do not understand why this is happening as when I try to reproduce this issue with a new project everything seems to work fine, even with some of the menu items disabled. Any ideas are welcome.

please find attached the DPR, PAS and DFM that will show the problem:
DPR:

```
program GeoUTM;

uses
  Forms,
  GeoUTM_Main in 'GeoUTM_Main.pas' {GeoUTMForm},
  Vcl.Themes,
  Vcl.Styles;

{$R *.RES}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  TStyleManager.TrySetStyle('Aqua Light Slate');

  Application.CreateForm(TGeoUTMForm, GeoUTMForm);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

PAS:

```
unit GeoUTM_Main;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils,

  VCL.Forms, Vcl.Menus, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.ExtCtrls,
  Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.ComCtrls, Vcl.ToolWin, Vcl.Graphics, System.Classes;

type
  TGeoUTMForm = class(TForm)
    Bevel1: TBevel;
    Bevel2: TBevel;
    ComboBox_Route: TComboBox;
    Files1: TMenuItem;
    GroupBox1: TGroupBox;
    GroupBox2: TGroupBox;
    Label3: TLabel;
    Label4: TLabel;
    Lbl_data11: TLabel;
    Lbl_data12: TLabel;
    Lbl_data13: TLabel;
    Lbl_data14: TLabel;
    Lbl_data21: TLabel;
    Lbl_data22: TLabel;
    Lbl_data23: TLabel;
    Lbl_data24: TLabel;
    Lbl_GridTitle1: TLabel;
    Lbl_GridTitle2: TLabel;
    Lbl_Title_1: TLabel;
    Lbl_Title_2: TLabel;
    MainMenu1: TMainMenu;
    MI_Blockshift: TMenuItem;
    mi_Conversion: TMenuItem;
    mi_Crossing: TMenuItem;
    mi_DataConversion: TMenuItem;
    mi_DTM: TMenuItem;
    mi_Exit: TMenuItem;
    mi_GridInfo: TMenuItem;
    mi_KPlist: TMenuItem;
    mi_Route: TMenuItem;
    mi_Routeinfo: TMenuItem;
    mi_Routes: TMenuItem;
    mi_Views: TMenuItem;
    N11: TMenuItem;
    N8: TMenuItem;
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Panel2: TPanel;
    StatusBar: TStatusBar;
    TB_1: TToolButton;
    TB_2: TToolButton;
    TB_4: TToolButton;
    TB_5: TToolButton;
    Timer1: TTimer;
    ToolBar: TToolBar;
    ToolBtn_Conv: TToolButton;
    ToolBtn_Crds: TToolButton;
    ToolBtn_Export: TToolButton;
    ToolBtn_Grid: TToolButton;
    ToolBtn_Heights: TToolButton;
    ToolBtn_KPlist: TToolButton;
    ToolBtn_Left: TToolButton;
    ToolBtn_Load: TToolButton;
    ToolBtn_Right: TToolButton;
    ToolBtn_Route: TToolButton;
    ToolBtn_RouteInfo: TToolButton;
    ToolBtn_Save: TToolButton;
    ToolBtn_Xing: TToolButton;
    ToolButton_DecDigit: TToolButton;
    ToolButton_incDigit: TToolButton;
    ToolButton1: TToolButton;
    Worldmap1: TMenuItem;

    procedure FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);


    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);



  private
    procedure UpdateForm;
    procedure PanelUpdate;

     { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  GeoUTMForm: TGeoUTMForm;


{------------------------------------------------}
{------------------------------------------------}
{------------------------------------------------}
{------------------------------------------------}

implementation

{$R *.DFM}

Const
  Progname   = 'GeoUTM' ;

  GridTitle11 = 'Coordinates list';
  GridTitle12 = 'Route : ';
  GridTitle13 = 'KP list : ';
  GridTitle14 = 'Crossing list : ';

  GridTitle21 = 'Conversion';
  GridTitle22 = 'Grid info';
  GridTitle23 = 'Route info';

 var
   ProgramName : string;

{-----------------------------------}
{             FormCreate            }
{-----------------------------------}
procedure TGeoUTMForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
   sExe, txt:string;
   dummy : integer;
   Wtot : integer;

begin
  With Statusbar do
  begin

    Panels[1].text := '© HPH van Rossen';
    ProgramName := ExtractFileName(Application.ExeName);

    Panels[3].text := 'Version - Temp';
  end;

  Lbl_GridTitle1.caption := GridTitle11;
  Lbl_GridTitle2.caption := GridTitle21;
end;

{-----------------------------------}
{              FormShow             }
{-----------------------------------}
procedure TGeoUTMForm.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // UpdateForm;
end;

{-----------------------------------}
{            FormActivate           }
{-----------------------------------}
procedure TGeoUTMForm.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
begin
   UpdateForm;    // removing this one and move to OnShow solves the issue
end;

{-----------------------------------}
{             UpdateForm            }
{-----------------------------------}
procedure TGeoUTMForm.UpdateForm;

begin
  // Menu items in first tier
  mi_Routes.enabled      := false;         // This one is causing the problem
  mi_Blockshift.enabled  := true;


  // Menu items in 2nd and other tiers
  mi_KPlist.enabled := False;

  mi_Crossing.enabled   := False;
  mi_Route.enabled  := false;

  // Toolbar items
  Combobox_route.enabled := False;

  ToolBtn_Route.enabled   := False;
  ToolBtn_KPlist.enabled  := False ;
  ToolBtn_Xing.enabled    := False ;
  ToolBtn_Heights.enabled := False;

  ToolBtn_Export.enabled := False;

  ToolBtn_RouteInfo.enabled :=  false;
  ToolBtn_Grid.enabled      :=  true;

  PanelUpdate;
end;

{------------------------------------------------}
{                  PanelUpdate                   }
{------------------------------------------------}
procedure TGeoUTMForm.PanelUpdate;
begin
  With Statusbar do
  begin
    Panels[5].text := '' ;
    Panels[7].text := FormatDateTime('dd mmm yyyy',Now);
    Panels[9].text := FormatDateTime('h:nn:ss AM/PM',Now);
  end;
end;

{------------------------------------------------}
{                Timer1Timer                     }
{------------------------------------------------}
procedure TGeoUTMForm.Timer1Timer(Sender: TObject);
begin
  PanelUpdate;
end;

end.
```

and finally the DFM:

```
object GeoUTMForm: TGeoUTMForm
  Left = 201
  Top = 59
  HelpContext = 40
  BorderIcons = [biSystemMenu, biMinimize]
  BorderStyle = bsSingle
  Caption = 'GeoUTM'
  ClientHeight = 676
  ClientWidth = 900
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Arial'
  Font.Style = []
  Menu = MainMenu1
  OldCreateOrder = False
  Position = poDesktopCenter
  Visible = True
  OnActivate = FormActivate
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  OnShow = FormShow
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 14
  object Bevel1: TBevel
    Left = 10
    Top = 136
    Width = 225
    Height = 97
    Shape = bsFrame
    Style = bsRaised
  end
  object Bevel2: TBevel
    Left = 10
    Top = 32
    Width = 225
    Height = 89
    ParentShowHint = False
    Shape = bsFrame
    ShowHint = False
    Style = bsRaised
  end
  object Label3: TLabel
    Left = 304
    Top = 320
    Width = 368
    Height = 24
    Caption = 'The license on GeoUTM has expired '
    Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
    Font.Color = clBlack
    Font.Height = -21
    Font.Name = 'Arial'
    Font.Style = [fsBold]
    ParentFont = False
  end
  object Label4: TLabel
    Left = 264
    Top = 352
    Width = 445
    Height = 16
    Caption = 
      'Please use "e-mail feedback" option to request for an updated ve' +
      'rsion'
    Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
    Font.Color = clBlack
    Font.Height = -13
    Font.Name = 'Arial'
    Font.Style = [fsBold]
    ParentFont = False
  end
  object Panel2: TPanel
    Left = 576
    Top = 136
    Width = 289
    Height = 97
    BevelOuter = bvNone
    Color = 4194304
    Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
    Font.Color = clWhite
    Font.Height = -11
    Font.Name = 'Arial'
    Font.Style = []
    ParentFont = False
    TabOrder = 5
    object Lbl_GridTitle1: TLabel
      Left = 0
      Top = 19
      Width = 289
      Height = 30
      Alignment = taCenter
      AutoSize = False
      Caption = 'Lbl_GridTitle1'
      Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
      Font.Color = clWhite
      Font.Height = -13
      Font.Name = 'Arial'
      Font.Style = [fsBold]
      ParentFont = False
    end
    object Lbl_GridTitle2: TLabel
      Left = 0
      Top = 54
      Width = 289
      Height = 19
      Alignment = taCenter
      AutoSize = False
      Caption = 'Lbl_GridTitle2'
      Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
      Font.Color = clWhite
      Font.Height = -13
      Font.Name = 'Arial'
      Font.Style = [fsBold]
      ParentFont = False
    end
  end
  object StatusBar: TStatusBar
    Left = 0
    Top = 657
    Width = 900
    Height = 19
    Panels = <
      item
        Alignment = taCenter
        Bevel = pbNone
        Width = 25
      end
      item
        Alignment = taCenter
        Width = 120
      end
      item
        Alignment = taCenter
        Bevel = pbNone
        Width = 30
      end
      item
        Alignment = taCenter
        Width = 100
      end
      item
        Alignment = taCenter
        Bevel = pbNone
        Width = 30
      end
      item
        Alignment = taCenter
        Width = 200
      end
      item
        Alignment = taCenter
        Bevel = pbNone
        Width = 30
      end
      item
        Alignment = taCenter
        Width = 100
      end
      item
        Alignment = taCenter
        Bevel = pbNone
        Width = 30
      end
      item
        Alignment = taCenter
        Width = 100
      end
      item
        Alignment = taCenter
        Bevel = pbNone
        Width = 15
      end>
  end
  object GroupBox1: TGroupBox
    Left = 243
    Top = 129
    Width = 312
    Height = 105
    Caption = ' 1st data set  '
    Color = clBtnFace
    Ctl3D = True
    Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
    Font.Color = clBlack
    Font.Height = -11
    Font.Name = 'Arial'
    Font.Style = []
    ParentBackground = False
    ParentColor = False
    ParentCtl3D = False
    ParentFont = False
    TabOrder = 0
    object Lbl_data12: TLabel
      Left = 39
      Top = 40
      Width = 221
      Height = 16
      Alignment = taCenter
      AutoSize = False
      Caption = 'Spheroid : Hayford / International'
    end
    object Lbl_data13: TLabel
      Left = 39
      Top = 64
      Width = 221
      Height = 16
      Alignment = taCenter
      AutoSize = False
      Caption = 'Central Meridian : 3'#176' East'
    end
    object Lbl_data11: TLabel
      Left = 39
      Top = 16
      Width = 221
      Height = 16
      Alignment = taCenter
      AutoSize = False
      Caption = 'Universal Transverse Mercator (UTM)'
      Font.Charset = ANSI_CHARSET
      Font.Color = clBlack
      Font.Height = -12
      Font.Name = 'Arial'
      Font.Style = [fsBold, fsUnderline]
      ParentFont = False
    end
    object Lbl_data14: TLabel
      Left = 39
      Top = 84
      Width = 221
      Height = 16
      Alignment = taCenter
      AutoSize = False
      Caption = 'Zone 31'
    end
  end
  object GroupBox2: TGroupBox
    Left = 561
    Top = 130
    Width = 312
    Height = 105
    Caption = ' 2nd data set  '
    Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
    Font.Color = clBlack
    Font.Height = -11
    Font.Name = 'Arial'
    Font.Style = []
    ParentBackground = False
    ParentFont = False
    TabOrder = 1
    Visible = False
    object Lbl_data22: TLabel
      Left = 47
      Top = 40
      Width = 221
      Height = 25
      Alignment = taCenter
      AutoSize = False
      Caption = 'Spheroid : Hayford / International'
      Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
      Font.Color = clBlack
      Font.Height = -12
      Font.Name = 'Arial'
      Font.Style = []
      ParentFont = False
    end
    object Lbl_data23: TLabel
      Left = 47
      Top = 64
      Width = 221
      Height = 16
      Alignment = taCenter
      AutoSize = False
      Caption = 'Central Meridian : 3'#176' East'
      Font.Charset = ANSI_CHARSET
      Font.Color = clBlack
      Font.Height = -12
      Font.Name = 'Arial'
      Font.Style = []
      ParentFont = False
    end
    object Lbl_data21: TLabel
      Left = 47
      Top = 16
      Width = 221
      Height = 16
      Alignment = taCenter
      AutoSize = False
      Caption = 'Geographical coordinates'
      Font.Charset = ANSI_CHARSET
      Font.Color = clBlack
      Font.Height = -12
      Font.Name = 'Arial'
      Font.Style = [fsBold, fsUnderline]
      ParentFont = False
    end
    object Lbl_data24: TLabel
      Left = 47
      Top = 84
      Width = 221
      Height = 16
      Alignment = taCenter
      AutoSize = False
      Caption = 'Zone 31'
      Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
      Font.Color = clBlack
      Font.Height = -12
      Font.Name = 'Arial'
      Font.Style = []
      ParentFont = False
    end
  end
  object Panel1: TPanel
    Left = 243
    Top = 32
    Width = 630
    Height = 89
    BevelInner = bvLowered
    ParentColor = True
    TabOrder = 2
    object Lbl_Title_2: TLabel
      Left = 128
      Top = 56
      Width = 377
      Height = 25
      Alignment = taCenter
      AutoSize = False
      Caption = 'Coordinate Conversion and Routing Program'
      Font.Charset = ANSI_CHARSET
      Font.Color = clBlack
      Font.Height = -16
      Font.Name = 'Arial'
      Font.Style = [fsBold]
      ParentFont = False
    end
    object Lbl_Title_1: TLabel
      Left = 240
      Top = 8
      Width = 131
      Height = 37
      Caption = 'GeoUTM'
      Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
      Font.Color = clBlack
      Font.Height = -32
      Font.Name = 'Arial'
      Font.Style = [fsBold, fsUnderline]
      ParentFont = False
    end
  end
  object ToolBar: TToolBar
    Left = 0
    Top = 0
    Width = 900
    Height = 22
    ButtonHeight = 30
    ButtonWidth = 38
    Caption = 'ToolBar'
    Color = clBtnFace
    DrawingStyle = dsGradient
    Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
    Font.Color = clWindowText
    Font.Height = -11
    Font.Name = 'Arial'
    Font.Style = []
    ParentColor = False
    ParentFont = False
    ShowCaptions = True
    TabOrder = 3
    Transparent = False
    object ToolButton1: TToolButton
      Left = 0
      Top = 0
      Width = 12
      Caption = 'ToolButton1'
      ImageIndex = 12
      Style = tbsSeparator
    end
    object ToolBtn_Load: TToolButton
      Left = 12
      Top = 0
      Caption = 'TB1'
      ImageIndex = 0
      ParentShowHint = False
      ShowHint = True
      Style = tbsDropDown
    end
    object ToolBtn_Save: TToolButton
      Left = 65
      Top = 0
      Caption = 'TB2'
      ImageIndex = 1
      ParentShowHint = False
      ShowHint = True
      Style = tbsDropDown
    end
    object ToolBtn_Export: TToolButton
      Left = 118
      Top = 0
      Caption = 'TB3'
      ImageIndex = 16
      ParentShowHint = False
      ShowHint = False
    end
    object TB_1: TToolButton
      Left = 156
      Top = 0
      Width = 18
      Caption = 'TB_1'
      ImageIndex = 2
      Style = tbsSeparator
    end
    object ToolBtn_Heights: TToolButton
      Left = 174
      Top = 0
      Caption = 'TB4'
      ImageIndex = 6
    end
    object TB_2: TToolButton
      Left = 212
      Top = 0
      Width = 18
      Caption = 'TB_2'
      ImageIndex = 2
      Style = tbsSeparator
    end
    object ToolBtn_Crds: TToolButton
      Left = 230
      Top = 0
      Hint = 'Show Coordinates'
      Caption = 'TB5'
      Down = True
      Grouped = True
      ImageIndex = 7
      ParentShowHint = False
      ShowHint = True
      Style = tbsCheck
    end
    object ToolBtn_Left: TToolButton
      Left = 268
      Top = 0
      Caption = 'TB6'
      Enabled = False
      ImageIndex = 13
    end
    object ComboBox_Route: TComboBox
      Left = 306
      Top = 0
      Width = 152
      Height = 22
      Style = csDropDownList
      TabOrder = 0
      Items.Strings = (
        'Route 1'
        'Route 2'
        'Route 3'
        'Route 4'
        'Route 5'
        'Route 6'
        'Route 7'
        'Route 8'
        'Route 9'
        'Route 10'
        '')
    end
    object ToolBtn_Right: TToolButton
      Left = 458
      Top = 0
      Caption = 'TB7'
      Enabled = False
      ImageIndex = 14
    end
    object ToolBtn_Route: TToolButton
      Left = 496
      Top = 0
      Caption = 'TB8'
      Grouped = True
      ImageIndex = 9
      ParentShowHint = False
      ShowHint = True
      Style = tbsCheck
    end
    object ToolBtn_KPlist: TToolButton
      Left = 534
      Top = 0
      Caption = 'TB9'
      Grouped = True
      ImageIndex = 8
      Style = tbsCheck
    end
    object ToolBtn_Xing: TToolButton
      Left = 572
      Top = 0
      Caption = 'TB10'
      Grouped = True
      ImageIndex = 10
      ParentShowHint = False
      ShowHint = True
      Style = tbsCheck
    end
    object TB_4: TToolButton
      Left = 610
      Top = 0
      Width = 30
      Caption = 'TB_4'
      ImageIndex = 4
      Style = tbsSeparator
    end
    object ToolBtn_Conv: TToolButton
      Left = 640
      Top = 0
      Hint = 'Show Conversion'
      Caption = 'TB11'
      Down = True
      Grouped = True
      ImageIndex = 2
      ParentShowHint = False
      ShowHint = True
      Style = tbsCheck
    end
    object ToolBtn_RouteInfo: TToolButton
      Left = 678
      Top = 0
      Hint = 'Show Routing Info'
      Caption = 'TB12'
      Grouped = True
      ImageIndex = 4
      ParentShowHint = False
      ShowHint = True
      Style = tbsCheck
    end
    object ToolBtn_Grid: TToolButton
      Left = 716
      Top = 0
      Hint = 'Show Grid Info'
      Caption = 'TB13'
      Grouped = True
      ImageIndex = 3
      ParentShowHint = False
      ShowHint = True
      Style = tbsCheck
    end
    object TB_5: TToolButton
      Left = 754
      Top = 0
      Width = 28
      Caption = 'TB_5'
      ImageIndex = 4
      Style = tbsSeparator
    end
    object ToolButton_incDigit: TToolButton
      Left = 782
      Top = 0
      Hint = 'Increase decimal'
      Caption = 'TB14'
      ImageIndex = 11
      ParentShowHint = False
      ShowHint = True
    end
    object ToolButton_DecDigit: TToolButton
      Left = 820
      Top = 0
      Hint = 'Decrease decimal'
      Caption = 'TB15'
      ImageIndex = 12
      ParentShowHint = False
      ShowHint = True
    end
  end
  object Timer1: TTimer
    OnTimer = Timer1Timer
    Left = 8
    Top = 296
  end
  object MainMenu1: TMainMenu
    Left = 16
    Top = 240
    object Files1: TMenuItem
      Caption = 'Files'
      object mi_Exit: TMenuItem
        Caption = 'Exit'
      end
    end
    object mi_Views: TMenuItem
      Caption = 'Views'
      object mi_DataConversion: TMenuItem
        Caption = 'Data conversion'
      end
      object mi_GridInfo: TMenuItem
        Caption = 'Grid info'
      end
      object mi_Routeinfo: TMenuItem
        Caption = 'Route info'
      end
      object N8: TMenuItem
        Caption = '-'
      end
      object N11: TMenuItem
        Caption = '-'
      end
    end
    object mi_Conversion: TMenuItem
      Caption = 'Conversion'
    end
    object mi_Routes: TMenuItem
      Caption = 'Routes'
      object mi_Route: TMenuItem
        Caption = 'Routes'
      end
      object mi_KPlist: TMenuItem
        Caption = 'KP list'
      end
      object mi_Crossing: TMenuItem
        Caption = 'Crossings'
      end
    end
    object mi_DTM: TMenuItem
      Caption = 'DTM'
    end
    object MI_Blockshift: TMenuItem
      Caption = 'Block-Shift'
    end
    object Worldmap1: TMenuItem
      Caption = 'Worldmap'
    end
  end
end
```

I hope this will be sufficient for you to repeat the issue.

Comment: Is this VCL styles rather than FMX? VCL styles are pretty buggy, certainly in XE5. Rodrigo Ruz is the expert on this subject and his VCL Style Utils does have some fixes. Beyond that a [mcve] is probably needed for us to give you detailed help. Otherwise we won't be sure that we are looking at the same problem/code as you are.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It is true that I am using VCL but also with the latest VCL.Style.Utils I get the same result.  Could it be linked to the 'Access Violation in module 'BindComp190.BPL' I get when opening the project?   In any case, I seem to have found a way around my problem by including my FormUpdate routine (enabling and disabling menu items) in the OnShow event instead of the OnActivate event of the main form.

Comment: This is why having a reproduction would help us. For sure when you set properties can matter.

Comment: @David, I removed most of the program and ended up with an almost empty mainform that still shows above phenomenon (at least on my XE5). If you are interested please let me know where to send the zipped source code.

Comment: Here on SO we don't really like off site links to code. We prefer the code in the question. You'd need a .dpr file, a .pas file, and a .dfm file. Edit them into the question and that's a [mcve].

Comment: You should not ask a new question. Edit this one. Click the edit button beneath the question tags.